# Error 127 when trying to run Zookeeper through supervisord?

Tags: supervisord, zookeeper

I'm getting `(exit status 127; not expected)` when I try to run Zookeeper through supervisord, and the errors I'm getting back aren't helpful. Running it as the normal user works just fine:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-1-90-214 zookeeper-3.4.6]$ sudo bin/zkServer.sh start
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/ec2-user/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
```

But when running it through supervisord (with -n, so I can see the output):

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-1-90-214 zookeeper-3.4.6]$ supervisord -n
2015-04-20 21:51:51,834 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2015-04-20 21:51:51,834 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2015-04-20 21:51:51,834 INFO supervisord started with pid 24004
2015-04-20 21:51:52,836 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 24007
2015-04-20 21:51:52,841 INFO exited: zookeeper (exit status 127; not expected)
```

The relevant part of `/etc/supervisord.conf`:

```
[program:zookeeper]
command=/home/ec2-user/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/zkServer.sh start -c /etc/supervisord.conf
autorestart=true
user=ec2-user
```

I've tried tinkering with all sorts of settings such as exitcodes and the like. Any ideas?

Comment: Did anything get logged in the zookeeper log? One thing that might interfere is that the default path search for ZK config doesn't work when it is not run from the ZK root folder?

Answer (score 1):

The command line seems incorrect:

```
/home/ec2-user/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/zkServer.cmd start -c /etc/supervisord.conf
```

zkServer.cmd would be the command for Windows and the config file is not the right one either.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo there; I'm running `zkServer.sh`, not `.cmd`; this is Linux.